# How to check device has WiFi Direct capability

Tags: wifi-direct, wifip2p, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I want to setup WiFi direct on my target.

Output of `iw list`

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
Band 1:

Band 2:
    software interface modes (can always be added):
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ IBSS, managed, AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 4,
           total <= 4, #channels <= 2, STA/AP BI must match
```

Looking at the above output I have following doubts:

1. How can I confirm whether my device supports WiFi direct feature or not.
2. What are software interface modes (can they be configured to WiFi Direct)

I tried the steps mentioned in particular link

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMAP_Wireless_Connectivity_NLCP_WiFi_Direct_Configuration_Scripts#P2P_usecases

But when I run `p2p_find` under `wpa_cli` terminal it every time it returns `FAIL`

Please guide where I am going wrong and how can I setup and configure WiFi direct in my target.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wi-Fi Direct feature was disabled in the driver installed, so I was not able to configure my device for Wi-Fi direct.

So to answer my questions, this is the output of `iw list` after enabling the Wi-Fi direct bit in driver module.

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * P2P client
     * P2P Go
Band 1:

Band 2:
    software interface modes (can always be added):
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ IBSS, managed, AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 4,
           total <= 4, #channels <= 2, STA/AP BI must match
```

What are software interface modes (can they be configured to WiFi Direct)?

*Software interface modes suggests the different interface modes supported by the driver but all may not be enabled at present.*

All the enabled interfaces are listed under **Supported interface modes:**